# Numpy: determine the shape after broadcast

Tags: python, numpy

I have shapes of 2 numpy arrays. I would like to check whether addition of these arrays is possible and determine the resulting shape.

Is there any way to do that quickly and to cover all the edge cases?

Comment: For 'addition' you need the same shape. Do you mean concatenating the arrays?

Comment: No. I don't need same shapes: np.array([1,2])+np.array([[10,1], [11, 12]])

Comment: @roadrunner66: Sounds like you haven't heard about one of NumPy's great features, [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: @user2357112 I don't think that's a duplicate. First of all, in my question I am only giving shapes + I also want to know the resulting shape

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski: The answers together cover that. For example, the `as_strided` answer can be modified to return the `shape` of the broadcasting result.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh, thats a very nice exampe, did not notice it! Thanks!

Comment: Since this answer has been closed, I want to propose a compact expression for this, in case it helps anyone. `broadcast_shape = tuple(l1 if l1 == l2 else max(l1, l2) for l1, l2 in itertools.zip_longest(shape1[::-1], shape2[::-1], fillvalue=1))[::-1]`

Comment: Ever notice how questions are often closed as a duplicate even though they are not actually duplicates of the linked question?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the actual NumPy objects, you could use NumPy's logic to determine this (addition requires broadcasting, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html)):

```
def checkShapes(a, b):
  try:
    return (np.broadcast(a, b)).shape
  except:
    return (-1,)
```

Comment: Thanks! More general case would be perfect though. Is there a way to create a fake array without actually using the memory so that I am able to use np.broadcast?

Comment: Why are you assuming 1-dimensional arrays in the first snippet, and why are you doing that weird `len` check in the second?

Comment: @user2357112 My mistake, I took array to mean one-dimensional, but looking at the docs, it can have n dimensions. As for the the weird if, the docs say "Subject to certain constraints, the smaller array is 'broadcast' across the larger array so that they have compatible shapes"

Comment: @AlexO'Neill: Broadcasting is commutative; it doesn't have to be smaller array first.

Comment: @user2357112 Great! Thanks. I've edited the answer.